# 3 domains in grails, I want to access 3rd domain which is unassociated to the 2nd domain in 2nd domains view

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-controller

Im stuck again. Its very frustrating coming from a ruby background.

I have 3 domains. Domain A has many domain B's. Domain A hasMany Domain C's

I want to be able to access domain C's records in domain B's view so a user can select a domain C template and have it inserted into the textarea of domain B's edit/create field. Obviously this will come after with javascript.

The story - A user creates a publication which is attached to a portfolio. The user when creating or editing a publication can choose a template to insert into a publication. The user should be able to choose from a list of templates assigned to the portfolio and when they choose a template from a list, it automaticaly inserts to the textarea of that publication during edit or create.

My issue is that I cannot get domain C to load any results in the domain B view. Nothing at all. I have tried g:select, g:link, href, what ever I try I can seem to get any results showing.

The views/controllers are standard template generated.

My domains/models are as follows

```
class Portfolio {

    static hasMany = [publications:Publication, pubtempl: Templatepublication]

class Publication {

    static belongsTo = [portfolio: Portfolio]

class Templatepublication {

   Cstatic belongsTo = [portfolio: Portfolio]
```

Edit:

this is the gsp page tags being used

```
<g:select name="templatepublication.id"
from="${spotlight.pubtemplates.Templatepublication.list()}" 
optionKey="id" required="" 
value="${portfolioInstance?.pubtempl?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>`
```

Comment: how do you use them to get access? did you try `B.portfolio.pubtempl`?

Comment: I think Igor and Victor answered my question. Both of you have answered my question. Would you call this chaining in grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are trying to do "in domain B view"? Can you post your view code?

Like this? (I mostly copied a [grails documentation example](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/select.html))

```
<g:select name="bInstance.a.c.id"
      from="${C.list()}"
      value="${bInstance.a?.c?.id}"
      optionKey="id" />
```

Comment: Yes I used the doc examples, but I have been trying to get params from A, while B is being edited and thinking that I could pass it to A.C.id, and not using bInstance in the name or value

Comment: Then you need to also pass an A instance as a model from controller action: `def edit() { ... return [bInstance: someB, aInstance: someA] }`, and use that aInstance in view. If you're using scaffolding, you can override only this one action.